# When to use LocationManager or Google Apis to get location

Tags: android, google-api

There is [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) class to get location but also you can use [Google Apis with LocationServices.API](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Right now I just want to know, using low battery, on which country is the user.

Which one should I use and when?

Comment: As per my aspect `Google Location API Services` is best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : LocationManager vs Google Play Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022662/android-locationmanager-vs-google-play-services)

Answer (score 2):

Google recommends that you to use the new Google Play Services Location APIs.

> The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11218105)

Comment: Thanks @sandrstar! Editing my post.