# Android location vs Google Play Services

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services, android-location

I've used both methods for my application and as expected I found Google Play Services to not only be more accurate but also a lot more stable and quicker. My question however is to why this is. I've read some differences between Android location and Google Play Services here and there, but I'd like to learn more about the underlying technologies used and why there is such a great difference in performance.

I hope someone can share an article with relevant information or share his or her own knowledge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/33023788/1443888

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : LocationManager vs Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022662/android-locationmanager-vs-google-play-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [Dhruvam Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2466859/dhruvam-gupta) on the question [Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443888/singh) provided:

The Google Location Services API, part of Google Play Services, provides a more powerful, high-level framework that automatically handles location providers, user movement, and location accuracy. It also handles location update scheduling based on power consumption parameters you provide. In most cases, you’ll get better battery performance, as well as more appropriate accuracy, by using the Location Services API.

More detailed differences between the two apis Google Play Service Location API and Android Framework Location API can be found [here](https://antoniohongkr.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/google-play-service-analysis-4-choice-between-google-play-location-service-and-android-location-service/)