# Android GPS location tracking for China

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

Im developing an android application for china which will need GPS location tracking.
For location tracking android needs access to Google play services.But Google play services is blocked for china.

Any workaround for this issue ? Any recommended 3rd party library or implementation?

Thanks

Comment: You can use traditional gps location collection and filtering yourself. You may already known this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Thanks.I use above code to get location in chinese tablet(Huawei M2 -A01L) and its not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `android.location.LocationManager` from the system, implement the `LocationListener`, and call the `requestLocationUpdates` on the `LocationManager`

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

For more information see [dosc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023788/4837089) answer.

Comment: Thanks.I use above code to get location in chinese tablet(Huawei M2 -A01L) and its not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1. LocationManager, doesn't require Google Play Services. This
   documentation mentions about it perfectly
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
2. BaiduLocation, seems like this is suitable for China and doesn't
   have English documentation. AFAIK, Wechat uses this too,
   http://developer.baidu.com/map/geosdk-android-developv3.3.htm

---

Almost i don't have any experience on BaiduLocation. All documentation is Chinese. If you look below link, it mentions about location modes like Device_Sensors, Battery_Saving, Hight_Accuracy. Maybe this is what you wish.

http://wiki.lbsyun.baidu.com/cms/androidloc/doc/v7.0/index.html

```
// This is simplified example from github
// https://github.com/buqing2009/GCS_Baidu_Advance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lingmutec/buqing2009/gcs_baidu_advance/BaiduMapFragment.java
private LocationClient mLocationClient = null;

public void requestLocationUpdates() {
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext());

    LocationClientOption option = new LocationClientOption();
    option.setLocationMode(LocationClientOption.LocationMode.Hight_Accuracy);
    option.setOpenGps(true);
    option.setCoorType("bd09ll");
    option.setScanSpan(1000);
    mLocationClient.setLocOption(option);

    mLocationClient.registerLocationListener(new BDLocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveLocation(BDLocation location) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Is BaiduLocation can get the location without internet connectivity ?Like  we can do it using Google play service (using GPS provider)