# Fused Location GPS doesn't update until opening Google Maps

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using fused location provider in my app which is set to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` at an interval of 60 seconds. This usually works but sometimes the location doesn't update for 5 to 10 minutes by itself, and I when I open Google Maps, it seems to trigger a location update.

Anyone else here who might have run into this issue or knows of the possible causes behind this behavior? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the fine location permission?

Comment: Yes, both fine and coarse.

Comment: Did you request location updates or are you periodically polling the `getLastLocation()` method?

Comment: I'm requesting location through `onLocationChanged()` method.

Comment: @Zishan did you solve your problem? Have the same prob? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: @IgorTyulkanov I don't exactly recall but I ended up using push notifications to trigger the app to start the service and followed by subsequent push notifications that got it to send location updated.

Comment: > This usually works but sometimes the location doesn't update for 5 to 10 minutes by itself.

Did you sit in the same place while this happened?

Comment: I ran into the same problem and switching the location mode of the device resolved the problem.
You can access location mode (Samsung):
Settings->Location->Location method->High accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gps does not always return a location even it's available through FusedLocationProvider api or LocationManager `LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`. Especially, if you are indoors it's less likely to get location from Gps depending on your device's Gps chip. Gps must be fixed to return a location.

You can write a test app which has LocationManager with Gps, Wifi and GpsStatusListener to check satellite count, satellites in the fix, and satellite signal strength and compare it with FusedLocationProvider at the same time and add the locations provided to map as markers.  You can also look for [Location.getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getExtras())  for FLP which may contain info about satellites. Even if LocationManager Gps is available and satellite count is 2 i can not get a location from Gps.

Hello World in image should be Gps location but it's not returned since it's not fixed yet.
[image: LocationManager Gps Status test]
Testing may not solve your problem but you can compare situations you get location or you can not for example it may required to use 3 satellites to get location from Gps or minimum signal strength. It may also take too long for Gps to lock and status on `GpsStatusListener` is set to `GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX` when it's locked. It took about 5 minutes for me Gps to get fixed and return a location. I also wrote another test with maps and i had the same issue until Gps is fixed on both LocationManager and FLP.

Answer (score 2):

My findings from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022662/android-locationmanager-vs-google-play-services) the Fused Location Provider will only maintain background location if at least one client is connected to it. Once the first client connects, it will immediately try to get a location. If your activity is the first client to connect and you call `getLastLocation()` right away in `onConnected()`, that might not be enough time for the first location to come in. This will result in the location being `null`.

To solve this issue, you have to wait (indeterminately) till the provider gets the location and then call `getLastLocation()`, which is impossible to know.

Another (better) option is to implement the `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` interface to receive periodic location updates (and switch it off once you get the first update).