# When trying to request for location using LocationRequest.Builder getting error on the Builder. how to fix?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, google-maps

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:public constructor Builder(locationRequest: LocationRequest) defined in android.location.LocationRequest.Builder public constructor Builder(intervalMillis: Long) defined in android.location.LocationRequest.Builder

```
private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
        val locationInterval = 1000
        val locationFastestInterval = 500
        val locationMaxWaitTime = 500
        var locationRequest =
            LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, locationInterval)
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(locationFastestInterval)
                .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(locationMaxWaitTime)
                .build()
        
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have imported the wrong class. From the code you have written, it seems like you want to use [`com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.Builder), which is a part of the [Google Play Services API](https://developers.google.com/android). But from your error message, it seems like you imported [`android.location.LocationRequest.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/LocationRequest.Builder), which is a part of the Android SDK. These are parts of two different location APIs.

If it is indeed your intention to use Google Play Services, check what you imported and change it accordingly. Make sure you have [installed the dependency](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33022662/5133585) for the differences between the two APIs.